# Refining the JavaScript indexOf statement

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a simple search algorithm in JavaScript.

```
var title = "The Greatest Movie Ever Made is here!";
var search1 = "the greATEST movie";
var search2 = "here IS made"
var search3 = "ever movie greatest the"
```

Using **indexOf()** only returns search1 false but search2,3 are true as well. How would I write a simple search algorithm to recognise instances where the words may not be in the right order or clumped together?

Comment: What do you want the search algorithm to be?  Return true if any word is in the target phrase?  Return true if all the words are in the target phrase, but in any order?  Return true if a majority of the words are in the target phrase?

Comment: Also, do you need to match only whole words or are sub-word matches allowed?

Comment: Return true for sub-word and whole word matches

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise how difficult that would be - I've omitted search4!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a function that would tell you if all the words in the search string existed in the target without regard for case or word boundaries.

```
function findMatch(data, target) {
    var words = data.toUpperCase().split(/\s/);
    if (words.length === 0) {return(false);}
    var uTarget = target.toUpperCase().replace(/\s/, "");
    var matchCnt = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (uTarget.indexOf(words[i]) != -1) {
            ++matchCnt;
        }
    }
    return(matchCnt === words.length);
}
```

This algorithm does not force word boundaries so searching for "an" will match if the target contains "and" or "answer".  Enforcing word boundaries would take a little more code that understood what a valid word boundary was.

Comment: @methuselah - I don't understand what you're searching for in what type of data.  Can you describe what you're trying to do in your code?  What data structure are you trying to search for what?