# Search by keywords SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'd like to implement a search feature with php and mysql like the one found here: [Basecamp help](http://help.37signals.com/basecamp)

I can't figure it out though. My question is not about the ajax-instant stuff, but the query itself. <strike>I have it until it can search by the given keywords, but my problem is the order. It returns all rows where any of the given keywords can be found, but</strike>  I need it to order it by the number of occurrences obviously.

Again, my question is not about the ajax used in the example site.

Any suggestions for the query?

Edit: my query isnt that good actually, so I take that statement back. I'm quite lost. Should I try full-text search? I don't quite get it yet, but seems that could be the solution.

Comment: the example provided about seems more like jQuery client side search. Here is an article covering that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425018/refining-the-javascript-indexof-statement/8425062#comment10409520_8425062

Comment: "Again, my question is not about the ajax used in the example site." ...

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
order by len(mycolumn) - len(replace(mycolumn,@mysearch,'')) DESC
```

so for

```
test hey test 
test hello
```

For the first record :

len("test hey test") - len(replace("test hey test","test","")) = 13 - 5 = 8

For the second

len("test hello") - len(replace("test hello","")) = 10 - 6 = 4

So the first will be above the second (I added the DESC)

Comment: Can you explain what this does please?